# SQL Query to replace/delete part of a string that comes with a variable value, that can be in any part of the string

Tags: sql, string, replace, sql-update, ssms

I have a field that holds multiple parameters as one string

```
parameters = -start=0 -end=67 -median=12
```

This parameters can be in any order or non existent.
How can I get rid of one of the parameters, eg. median, and keep all the others in the string?

This query replaces the parameter but not the variable value that comes after the '='

```
UPDATE table
SET parameters = REPLACE(parameters,'-median=','')
where parameters LIKE '%median%'
```

How can I update this query to replace '-median=% ' ?

Comment: This is why you don't encode multiple values in a string in a relational database. You should have a parameter table with a column for the parameter type and another column for the value. You can always join them back to create your string, but SQL is notoriously bad at parsing strings. It can be done, but SQL is not the best language for it.

Comment: yeah I know this, but I am dealing with a very old database(not of my creation), that uses multiple values in strings like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
select params,
       (case when params like '% -median=%'
             then stuff(params, 
                        charindex(' -median', v.params),
                        charindex(' ', v.params + ' ', charindex('-median', v.params)) - charindex(' -median', v.params),
                        ''
                       )
              else params
       end)
from (values ('parameters = -start=0 -end=67 -median=12'),
             ('parameters = -start=0 -median=12  -end=67')
     ) v(params);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2570785cfa4ce5851eeb7d802cd62374) is the example in db<>fiddle.